# Delete Ubuntu from dual boot Windows 8.1 in GPT disk

Tags: windows, uninstall, format, mbr, gpt

I'm using Windows dual booting with Ubuntu.

I have uninstalled, and at that time my disk was formated as MBR. After deleting all partitions of Ubuntu I choose to rebuild the MBR in my disk. That way I was sure not to loose the Windows boot loader.

Now I'm using a GPT disk. I want to delete Ubuntu but I'm scared I will loose my Windows boot loader.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to get the run box, type `diskmgmt.msc` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

- Just click with right mouse button on the Ubuntu partition, and
  choose to Delete Volume.
- If Windows 8.1 was preinstalled on your computer, please ensure you
  don't remove recovery partitions, etc.
- The space formerly occupied by Linux should now say "Unallocated".
- And Now Right-click on C: and "Extend Volume" to increase the size of
  drive C using the unallocated space.(**NOTE:** *You can replace any drive letter instead of C: that you shrink it before for installing Ubuntu*)
- If you were using grub to dual-boot (most probably), then you may
  need the windows 8.1 CD to fix the boot manager and make Windows 8.1
  bootable again.

How to fix your boot manager :

1. boot your system using windows 8.1 installation CD or flash drive
2. go to "repair your system"
3. use command prompt (Troubleshoot ► Advanced Options ► Command Prompt)
4. type `bootrec /fixboot` then hit enter
5. type `bootrec /fixmbr` then hit enter
6. exit

This time your system will boot directly into windows.

This is the safe way to uninstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Hello guys.
My disk was formated as GPT. It's ok if i use command "bootrec /fixmbr" ?

Comment: Do you have windows 8.1 boot loader to select which OS starts or Ubuntu Grub boot loader?

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Tried dual w8.1/ubuntu in my laptop Samsung RPC512 and the OS(linux) broke after the system update.