# Trouble Uninstalling GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I recently uninstalled Ubuntu after having dual-booted Ubuntu and Windows. Now when I boot normally, I reach a screen that simply gives me a `grub` prompt. I can get to Windows by booting, pressing F11, and selecting "Windows Bootloader", but I would prefer to be able to go straight to Windows.

Per the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489929/delete-ubuntu-from-dual-boot-windows-8-1-in-gpt-disk), I tried running `bootrec /fixboot` and  `bootrec /fixmbr` in succession, which had no effect.

I then backed up my system on an external drive and attempted to reinstall from that, but I was unable to do so because "the system image was created with UEFI" instead of BIOS.

Thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Did you execute the `bootrec` commads on a recovery disk on in the installed windows system? Note there are other similar questions such as [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/178596) which have other options.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive might help if u need a recovery thing to boot from.

Comment: It sounds like you have a UEFI computer so running `bootrec /fixmbr` won't help (that installs the windows bootloader to the master boot record). Instead you should go into your 'BIOS' settings (F2 at boot or lookup in manual) and set Windows as the default OS to boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technically might not be uninstalling GRUB, but it produced the desired behavior (i.e., booting to Windows instead of GRUB). Here's what I did:

1. Open `cmd.exe` with administrator privileges
2. Run `bcdboot C:\Windows`, replacing `C` with the appropriate drive as necessary

That was it!